# text coming below profile instead of being lined below with username

Tags: html, css

I have a message div with profile icon on left and on right the username and just below it message. If the message is too long, it is showing like this:

[image: problem]

but what I want is that it should be aligned below the username.

my message show box code:

```html
<div id="show_msg">
    <div id="chat_box">
        <img src="images/user.jpg" id="onio_user_2"  style="border: 2px solid lightblue">
        <div class="content-2">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size:13px;">BaTuTa</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="content">
            <p><span>Han yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhaj bhaj wadna ay mandir maseeti
Te kaday mann apnay wich warya ee naai</span></p>
        </div>                          
    </div>
</div>
```

my css:

```css
#chat_box {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    position: absolute;
}
#chat_box img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.content {
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
}
.content p {
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    padding: 0;

}
.content-2 {
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
}
.content-2 p {
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    padding: 0;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to easily align content. I added a working code snippet.

1. Add `display: flex` to your `#chat_box` id to align the image and it's content next to each other.
2. Remove your `content_2` class and added the comment part of your content to your original `content` class. So now your `#chat_box` only contains 2 elements, an `img` and a `div` with your text. It's easier to align it properly this way.
3. Add a `min-width` and `min-height` property to your `img` so it doesn't get squashed.

```css
#chat_box {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  position: absolute;
  
  display: flex;
}

#chat_box img {
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.content {
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 3px;
}

.content p {
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.comment {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  padding: 0;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div id="show_msg">
  <div id="chat_box">
    <img src="images/user.jpg" id="onio_user_2" style="border: 2px solid lightblue">
    <div class="content-2">
      <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size:13px;">BaTuTa</p>
      <p class="comment"><span>Han yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhaj bhaj wadna ay mandir maseeti
Te kaday mann apnay wich warya ee naai</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: appears to be working, but the distance between the username and comment is too much

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<br /> + <div class="content">` as below.
Since you have a `<p>` you do not need a `<br/>` to go in the next line

```
<div id="show_msg">
                  <div id="chat_box">
                    <img src="images/user.jpg" id="onio_user_2"  style="border: 2px solid lightblue">
                      <div class="content-2">
                          <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size:13px;">BaTuTa</p>

                          <p><span>Han yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahi kaha ap nayHan yaar sahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhajsahiBhaj bhaj wadna ay mandir maseeti
    Te kaday mann apnay wich warya ee naai</span></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

css

```
  #chat_box {
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px dotted black;
      position: absolute;
  }
  #chat_box img {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      float: left;
  }
  .content {
      font-size: 12px;
      float: left;
      margin: 0 0 0 3px;
  }
  .content p {
      margin: 0 0 1px 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
  .content-2 {
      font-size: 12px;

      margin: 0 0 0 3px;
  }
  .content-2 p {
      margin: 0 0 1px 0;
      padding: 0;
      word-break: break-all;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add profile name with description text in same box try this:

```
<div id="show_msg"><div id="chat_box"><img src="images/user.jpg" id="onio_user_2" style="border: 2px solid lightblue"><div class="content-2"><p style="font-weight: bold;font-size:13px;">BaTuTa</p><p class="comment">lorem ipsum is a dummy text which goes here</p></div></div></div>
```

Css should be link

```
#chat_box img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: left;}

  .content {
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 0 0 3px;}
```

You can change max-width to width also if you face any problem, it will work perfect rest of css will be same like you used above only placing of content is wrong.